# HTML is being embedded in pdf source (iTextSharp)

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, itext

I was following an early example of creating a PDF in the book **iText in Action**.  I am using iTextSharp in a simple ASP.Net Webform to build the PDF. When viewing the source in UltraEdit I noticed that my HTML from the page was being embedded at the bottom of the file. I then checked a previous report we built in iTextSharp and noticed it had the HTML source embedded at the bottom (albeit in a compressed format). The HTML does not show up in the rendered PDF, just the source.

I am trying to figure out why this is happening and if there is a way to stop it.

On the page I have a button that triggers this event (The last block of this is code to have the document download locally. This is not in the example in the book):

```
protected void BtnSamplePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var document = new Document();
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memStream);
                document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A5);
                document.SetMargins(36, 72, 108, 180);
                document.SetMarginMirroringTopBottom(true);

                document.Open();

                PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContentUnder;
                writer.CompressionLevel = 0;
                canvas.SaveState();
                canvas.BeginText();
                canvas.MoveText(36, 788);
                canvas.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 12);
                canvas.ShowText("Hello World"); 
                canvas.EndText();
                canvas.RestoreState();

                document.Close();

                string fileName = "attachment;filename=" + "practice.pdf";
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", fileName);
                Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
                Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                Response.OutputStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

The pdf source starts with the typical headers

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
2 0 obj
<</Length 81/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
```

At the end though you can see that it appends the HTML from the calling page

```
</Size 7/Root 5 0 R/Info 6 0 R/ID [<aff0a4a6eb7e3827497db957aaef3eb3><aff0a4a6eb7e3827497db957aaef3eb3>]>>
%iText-5.5.1
startxref
620
%%EOF


<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
...
```

It continues with all the HTML from that page being embedded in the file.

Comment: I can't remember what parts of the pipeline start and end anymore but can you trying throwing `Response.Close()` in there, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BtnSamplePDF_Click will be doing a page postback - the rest of your code logic is fine, but as the page is being asked to be rendered, so you're getting those results.

If you change the code so that you're calling a handler (ashx) returning a byte[] it'll work.